# Using JQuery to carousel through divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create buttons, which are set as the li's within my code, and when certain ones are hovered it changes the content to a specific div, but when the items aren't hovered it carousels through the divs, and pauses when hovered. I've managed to create something, I think i'm almost there, it's quite sloppy but it does the job somewhat, when I hover over an item it displays both the carousel item and the hovered for a moment, my code is probably terrible, so I do apologise in advance. I also have a further question, is it possible to apply an :active style to the currently carouselled li, for example "Red" changes to red text. Thank you for any input or advice!

```js
//Show item on hover
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first").hover(function(){
        $('.div1').show();
  });
  $(".second").hover(function(){
        $('.div2').show();
  });
  $(".third").hover(function(){
        $('.div3').show();
  });
  $(".fourth").hover(function(){
        $('.div4').show();
  });
  $(".fifth").hover(function(){
        $('.div5').show();
  });
});
//Carousel with timer
var messages;
var curcontentindex = 0;
var prevcontentindex;
var futcontentindex;
var i;

function rotatecontent() {
    messages.hide();
    curcontentindex = (curcontentindex < messages.length - 1) ? curcontentindex + 1 : 0; 
    messages.get(curcontentindex).style.display = "block";
}

$(function() {
    messages = $('.carousel-content').find('div');
    i = setInterval(rotatecontent, 10000);


    $('.buttons li').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(i);
        
    }, function() {
        i = setInterval(rotatecontent, 10000);
        messages.hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="buttons">
  <li><a href="#" class="first">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="second">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="third">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fourth">Yellow</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fifth">Black</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel-content">
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="https://media.nisbets.com/asset/core/prodimage/medium/cg929_y_darkred_square.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div2" style="display:none">
    <img src="https://media.nisbets.com/asset/core/prodimage/medium/cg941_y_deepblue_square.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div3" style="display:none">
    <img src="http://pepperstreet.co.uk/clients/shipstonlink/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/dark-green-square.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="div4" style="display:none">
    <img src="https://b451c108ef7ce3b912eb-75c7695d67180639ae25fac6b37d4ead.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/onlinereality/uploads/colouroption/2_8148_t.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div5" style="display:none">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Black_square.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working fine, what do you want?

Comment: When you hover over one of the list items, it shows two divs at once, for a moment, as well as I was wondering if it's possible to have an active style for the current carousel item, sorry if it was badly worded :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirement :

1) shows two divs at once

2) have an active style in for the current carousel item

> Solution :
>
> - Apply hover event to `<a>` `$('.buttons li a')`
> - Hide all dive on mouse hover function using `messages.hide();`
> - Apply `active` class on mouse over and remove it on move out
> - Apply and remove same `active` class on `curcontentindex` change in `rotatecontent()` function
> - Update `curcontentindex` in mouse over by `li` index, to start timer from same position when its mouse out.

Please check below example :

```js
//Carousel with timer
var messages;
var curcontentindex = 0;
var prevcontentindex;
var futcontentindex;
var i;

function rotatecontent() {
    messages.hide();
    messages.get(curcontentindex).style.display = "block";
    $(".buttons li a").removeClass('active');
    $(".buttons li:eq(" + curcontentindex + ") a").addClass('active');
    curcontentindex = (curcontentindex < messages.length - 1) ? curcontentindex + 1 : 0;
}

$(function () {
    messages = $('.carousel-content').find('div');
    i = setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000);

    $('.buttons li a').hover(function () {
        clearInterval(i);

        $(".buttons li a").removeClass('active');
        curcontentindex = $(this).parent().index();
        messages.hide();///Hide all previous
        $('.carousel-content div:eq(' + curcontentindex + ')').show();
        $(this).addClass('active');

    }, function () {
        i = setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000);
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="buttons">
    <li><a href="#" class="first">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="second">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="third">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fourth">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fifth">Black</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel-content">
    <div class="div1">
        <img src="https://media.nisbets.com/asset/core/prodimage/medium/cg929_y_darkred_square.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="div2" style="display:none">
        <img src="https://media.nisbets.com/asset/core/prodimage/medium/cg941_y_deepblue_square.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="div3" style="display:none">
        <img src="http://pepperstreet.co.uk/clients/shipstonlink/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/dark-green-square.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="div4" style="display:none">
        <img src="https://b451c108ef7ce3b912eb-75c7695d67180639ae25fac6b37d4ead.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/onlinereality/uploads/colouroption/2_8148_t.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="div5" style="display:none">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Black_square.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>
```